# How do I turn array items into an object in SnapLogic

Tags: arrays, object, snaplogic

In SnapLogic, I have an input JSON like the one below, it appears to be an array.  I am trying to put it into a structure where it is an object called "remitLocations" composed of an array of addresses containing the following items. I have been trying to use mapper and structure snaps to do this.  I also tried using JSON and XML generators to give it the structure I want, but so far nothing has worked.

```
[
  {
    "addressInternalid": 2631363,
    "isDelete": false,
    "internalSupplierid": 3423589,
    "acctGrpid": "RT",
    "address1": "5309 GREENWAY",
    "address2": "5301 REDWAY",
    "address3": "5504 BLUEWAY",
    "poBox": "0912KHJWD",
    "country": "USA",
    "state": "US-TX",
    "city": "FREE",
    "zip": "78211",
    "phone": "2229808888",
    "phoneExtn": "091",
    "fax": "747",
    "faxExtn": "737",
    "fullCompanyName": "SUPPLIER MARCH 3 dba TEXT",
    "requestId": 5272423,
    "id": "3423589",
    "facilityCode": "0001",
    "systemCode": "1",
    "supplierType": "Operational",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "addressInternalid": 2631367,
    "isDelete": false,
    "internalSupplierid": 3423589,
    "acctGrpid": "RT",
    "address1": "11305 4 PTS DR",
    "address2": "BLDG 2,#100",
    "country": "USA",
    "state": "US-TX",
    "city": "AUSTIN",
    "zip": "78726",
    "phone": "5126648805",
    "phoneExtn": "123",
    "fax": "123",
    "faxExtn": "134",
    "fullCompanyName": "SUPPLIER MARCH 3 dba TEXT",
    "requestId": 5272423,
    "id": "3423589",
    "facilityCode": "0001",
    "systemCode": "1",
    "supplierType": "Operational",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "addressInternalid": 2631368,
    "isDelete": false,
    "internalSupplierid": 3423589,
    "acctGrpid": "RT",
    "address1": "REMIT 11305 4 PTS DR",
    "address2": "BLDG 3",
    "country": "USA",
    "state": "US-TX",
    "city": "AUSTIN",
    "zip": "78725",
    "phone": "5126600000",
    "phoneExtn": "678",
    "fax": "678",
    "faxExtn": "678",
    "fullCompanyName": "SUPPLIER MARCH 3 dba TEXT",
    "requestId": 5272423,
    "id": "3423589",
    "facilityCode": "0001",
    "systemCode": "1",
    "supplierType": "Operational",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:*** Answer contains two solutions. The bottom one seems to be a better solution because you use only one snap.

---

**Solution #1**

Use **JSON Formatter** to aggregate the incoming documents into a single JSON. Then use a **Binary to Document** Snap with encoding/decoding set to *None*. After that, you can just parse the content and put it under any field name in a mapper.

**Sample Pipeline:**

[image: Sample pipeline]

**Binary to Document:**

[image: binary to document]

**Final Mapper:**

[image: parsing json]

**Output:**

[image: output]

***Notes***

- No configuration was changed in the **JSON Formatter**
- Setting encoding/decoding to *None* in the **Binary to Document** Snap is important
- Parse the content like - `JSON.parse($content)`

---

**Solution #2**

There is actually a better way to do it - Use the "**Group By N** Snap with *Target Field* as `remitLocations` and *Group Size* as `0`.

> A value of 0 instructs the Snap to group all input documents into a single document.

**Sample Pipeline**

[image]

**Group By N**

[image]

**Output**

[image]